# iOS 17.4.1 requestTrackingAuthorization returns Denied status always

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I am trying to prompt App Tracking Transparency Request to the user, the prompt apears on the screen without any issues. But before the user select any of the two options from the prompt  requestTrackingAuthorizationStatus returns 'denied' status forever. I am facing the issue in iOS17 and above.

Is there any work around for this?

Comment: Where did you call the requestTrackingAuthorization() methoed? In addition, was **Settings -> Privacy -> Tracking** enabled?

Comment: I have edited my question. Yes, Tracking is enabled.